# observed data log likelihood and complete data log likelihood estimation

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, expectation-maximization, bernoulli-distribution

I have the following model.

$p(z_{n}) = Categorical(\pi)$

$p(\pi)  = Dir(\alpha)$

$p(x_{n}| z_{n}=k,\mu) = \prod_{d=1}^{D} {Bernouli(\mu_{kd})} $

$p(\mu_{kd}) = uniform(0,1)$

How can I find observed data log likelihood and complete data log likelihood.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe little bit more the model and especially the variables? Which variables are observed/latent/hyperparameters?

Comment: @xeon $ {\mu_{1}, \mu_{2},..\pi }$ are inferring parameters and $\alpha$ is known hyper parameter

Comment: can any one help me in solving this. @xeon I have added explanation of variables